# File system cleaner and registry cleaner for Windows 7

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, windows-registry, cleaner

Please recommend software to replace CCleaner for Windows 7.

Here is the *only* functionality from CCleaner required (it's fine if your recommendations do more):

1. File system cleaner

   - Remove temporary files
   - Remove junk files from previously installed applications
2. Registry cleaner

   - Fix obvious registry errors (without breaking anything)
   - Remove obsolete entries

I prefer it to error on the cautious side, rather than be over-aggressive.

Must be gratis for personal use.  Open-source preferred, but not required.

I'm fine if it takes two separate applications to meet these requirements.